# How to create a smoother heatmap

Tags: matlab, heatmap

I'd like to create a heat map to analyze the porosity of some specimens that I have 3D-printed. the X-Y coordinates are fixed since they are the positions in which the specimens are printed on the platform.

Heatmap:
[image: heatmap]

```
Tbl = readtable('Data/heatmap/above.csv');
X = Tbl(:,1);
Y = Tbl(:,2);
porosity = Tbl(:,3);
hmap_above = heatmap(Tbl, 'X', 'Y', 'ColorVariable', 'porosity');
```

- The first question is: how can I sort the Y-axis of the plot? since it goes from the lower value (top) to the higher value (bottom) and I need it the other way around.
- The second question is: I only have around 22 data points and most of the chart is without color, so I'd like to get a smoother heatmap without the black parts.

The data set is quite simple and is shown below:

| X | Y | porosity |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 74.4615 | 118.3773 | 0.039172163 |
| 84.8570 | 69.4699 | 0.046314637 |
| 95.2526 | 20.5625 | 0.041855213 |
| 105.6482 | -28.3449 | 0.049796110 |
| 116.0438 | -77.2522 | 0.045010692 |
| 25.5541 | 107.9817 | 0.038562053 |
| 35.9497 | 59.0743 | 0.041553065 |
| 46.3453 | 10.1669 | 0.036152061 |
| 56.7408 | -38.7404 | 0.060719664 |
| 67.1364 | -87.6478 | 0.037756115 |
| -23.3533 | 97.5861 | 0.052840845 |
| -12.9577 | 48.6787 | 0.045216851 |
| -2.5621 | -0.2286 | 0.033645353 |
| 7.8335 | -49.1360 | 0.030670865 |
| 18.2290 | -98.0434 | 0.024952472 |
| -72.2607 | 87.1905 | 0.036199237 |
| -61.8651 | 38.2831 | 0.026725885 |
| -51.4695 | -10.6242 | 0.029212058 |
| -41.0739 | -59.5316 | 0.028572611 |
| -30.6783 | -108.4390 | 0.036796151 |
| -121.1681 | 76.7949 | 0.031688096 |
| -110.7725 | 27.8876 | 0.034619855 |
| -100.3769 | -21.0198 | 0.039070101 |
| -89.9813 | -69.9272 | NaN |
| -79.5857 | -118.8346 | NaN |

Comment: Sounds like rotation and interpolation might help. If you have any more details about the table/array you're using then we might be a to give more specific implementation details.

Comment: Thanks, I just added the table used, which is quite simple

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to assign color to the "black parts" you will have to interpolate the porosity over a finer grid than you currently have.

The best tool for 2D interpolation over a uniformly sampled grid is [`griddata`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/griddata.html)

First you have to define the X-Y grid you want to interpolate over, and choose a suitable mesh density.

```
% this will be the number of points over each side of the grid
gridres = 100 ;
% create a uniform vector on X, from min to max value, made of "gridres" points
xs = linspace(min(X),max(X),gridres) ;
% create a uniform vector on Y, from min to max value, made of "gridres" points
ys = linspace(min(Y),max(Y),gridres) ;
% generate 2D grid coordinates from xs and ys
[xq,yq]=meshgrid(xs,ys) ;
% now interpolate the pososity over the new grid
InterpolatedPorosity = griddata(X,Y,porosity,xq,yq) ;

% Reverse the Y axis (flip the `yq` matrix upside down)
yq = flipud(yq) ;
```

Now my version of matlab does not have the `heatmap` function, so I'll just use `pcolor` for display.

```
% now display
hmap_above = pcolor(xq,yq,InterpolatedPorosity);
hmap_above.EdgeColor = [.5 .5 .5] ; % cosmetic adjustment
colorbar
colormap jet
title(['Gridres = ' num2str(gridres)])
```

---

And here are the results with different grid resolutions (the value of the `gridres` variable at the beginning):

[image: interpolated, shading flat]

Now you could also ask MATLAB to further graphically smooth the domain by calling:

```
shading interp
```

Which in the 2 cases above would yield:

[image: shadinf interp]

---

Notes: As you can see on the gridres=100, you original data are so scattered that at some point interpolating on a denser grid is not going to produce any meaningful improvment. No need to go overkill on your mesh density if you do not have enough data to start with.

Also, the `pcolor` function uses the matrix input in the opposite way than `heatmap`. If you use `heatmap`, you have to flip the Y matrix upside down as shown in the code. But if you end up using `pcolor`, then you don't need to flip the Y matrix.

The fact that I did it in the code (to show you how to do) made the result display in the wrong orientation for a display with `pcolor`. Simply comment the `yq = flipud(yq) ;` statement if you stick with `pcolor`.

---

Additionally, if you want to be able to follow the isolevels generated by the interpolation, you can use [`contour`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/contour.html) to add a layer of information:
Right after the code above, the lines:

```
hold on
contour(xq,yq,InterpolatedPorosity,20,'LineColor','k')
```

will yield:

[image: with contour]

Comment: I decided to change the function Heatmap to pcolor. It was very useful. Thanks